# User input of coordinate of depth view

Tags: c#, coordinates, user-input, kinect, point

I am trying to input manually the coordinates of a point on the Kinect depth camera view and to get the depth value of that point. I am having trouble making it actually prompt values for the coordinates on the main window and select that coordinate on the camera view (on the main window) and with making it user inputted. I want to be able to input a X- and a Y- coordinate.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        Point p1;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number.");
        string inputX = Console.ReadLine();
        double inputAsNumberX;
        if (double.TryParse(inputX, out inputAsNumberX) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered a valid number: {0}", inputAsNumberX);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number.");
        }


        p1.X = inputAsNumberX;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number.");
        string inputY = Console.ReadLine();
        double inputAsNumberY;
        if (double.TryParse(inputY, out inputAsNumberY) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered a valid number: {0}", inputAsNumberY);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number.");

        }
        p1.Y = inputAsNumberY;
```

I get an use of unassigned local variable 'p1'. - problem solved

How do I get it to prompt user input on the main window and have it linked to the depth image (depth camera view on the main window) coordinate???

Comment: try `Point p1 = new Point();`

Comment: The code is unrelated to Kinect.

Comment: I am trying to make it so the point relates to a coordinate on the Kinect depth camera view image on my main window, so it grabs the depth value.